# sql union on *similiar* column value

Tags: sql, sqlite

In a sqlite3 database, I have multiple tables that contain names of computers.

```
a.name, b.name, c.hostname, d.addr_host
```

I need to gather all of the hostnames for a subquery. However, these tables share simliar name values AND some of the tables have names that are simliar for example.

```
 1. a.name = machine001
 2. b.name = machine001.domainname
```

Is it possible to create a single column of all the hostnames using a query?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you simply want:

```
select a.name as hostname from a
union -- intentionally eliminate duplicates
select b.name from b
union
select c.hostname from c
union
select d.addr_host from d;
```

If you only want the name up to the first `'.'`, then:

```
select substr(a.name, 1, instr(a.name || '.', '.') - 1) as hostname from a
union -- intentionally eliminate duplicates
select substr(b.name, 1, instr(b.name || '.', '.') - 1) from b
union
select substr(c.hostname, 1, instr(a.name || '.', '.') - 1) from c
union
select substr(d.addr_host, 1, instr(d.addr_host || '.', '.') - 1) from d;
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain what is happening for each substring select?

Comment: Also is there a way to do something similiar using the like function?

https://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/core-functions-like.php

Comment: @JoshSharkey . . . "if you only want the name up to the first '.'" pretty much explains what the logic is.  `like` returns a boolean, so it is not an obvious function to use if you want a string.